# Laravel Vue components not recognized by PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, vue.js, phpstorm

I decided to start learning Vue with a new Laravel project I'm working on.

I added the example component that comes with Laravel in my `home.blade` view.

The problem is PhpStorm is telling me:

> Unknown html tag example-component

I have the `Vue.js` plugin enabled in PhpStorm and the component itself renders fine when I visit the `home` page.

How do I get PhpStorm to recognize my Laravel Vue components?

Comment: Install the laravel plugin for phpstorm.

Comment: It is installed and enabled.

Comment: Did you recompile the javascript with npm or yarn before using the component?

Comment: Try invalidating cache and restart the phpstorm

Comment: Seems to be working now. Thanks guys.

Comment: what file did you define your component in -`.vue` or `.blade`?